# re.sub doesn't replace the string when I execute the file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python script to practice the re.sub method. But when I use python3 to run the script, I figure out that the string in the file doesn't change.
Here is my location.txt file,

```
34.3416,108.9398
```

this is what regex.py contains,

```
import re
with open ('location.txt','r+') as second:
    content = second.read()
    content = re.sub('([-+]?\d{2}\.\d{4},[-+]?\d{2}\.\d{4})','44.9740,-93.2277',content)
    print (content)
```

I set up a print statement to test the output, and it gives me

```
34.3416,108.9398
```

which is not what I want. 
Then I change the "r+" to "w+", it completely removes the location.txt content. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Just eyeballing it... did you rather mean `([-+]?\d{2}\.\d{4},[-+]?\d{3}\.\d{4})`?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem you're asking about is: Are you looking only at whether the `print`ed output reflects the change (and asking why it doesn't), or do you expect the contents of the file to be updated? (If the latter, err -- which code do you think is accomplishing that update?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp has a problem as pointed by Andrej Kesely in the other answer. `\d{2}` should be `\d{2,3}`:

```
content = re.sub(r'([-+]?\d{2,3}\.\d{4},[-+]?\d{2,3}\.\d{4})', ,'44.9740,-93.2277',content)
```

After fixing that, you changed the string, but you didn't write it back to the file, you're only changing the variable in memory.

```
second.seek(0) # return to beginning of file
second.write(content) # write the data back to the file
second.truncate() # remove extraneous bytes (in case the content shrinked)
```

Comment: I add this at the end of my file, it still not working sir.

Comment: import re

with open ('location.txt','r+') as second:

    content = second.read()
    content = re.sub('([-+]?\d{2}\.\d{4},[-+]?\d{2}\.\d{4})',"44.9740,-93.2277",content)
    second.seek(0) 
    second.write(content) 
    second.truncate()

Comment: @PeterWang "Not working"? what do you get as result?

Comment: it works now, thank you for your help! The new problem is what the Andrej point out, I should do \d{2,3} but not \d{2}.

Comment: @PeterWang you also need my code if you want to write back to the file

Comment: you are right, I do use your code. What I mean is, after using your code, my code still have a problem which points out by Andrej.

Comment: @PeterWang oh right, I added that info to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The second number in your location.txt is 108.9398, which has 3 digits before dot and it doesn't match to your regexp. Change your regexp to:

```
([-+]?\d{2,3}\.\d{4},[-+]?\d{2,3}\.\d{4})
```

Online [regexp here](https://regex101.com/r/7dmoeK/2).